# Reason of removing apt/dpkg/lock & apt/archives/lock

Tags: apt, filesystem, dpkg, lock

Is it possible to install multiple packages by deleting " Using apt & dpkg in the same time ".

> dpkg/lock & /archives/lock

---

The Ubuntu Developers made it for reason "that you can not install multiple packages" .

so my question is :

Deleting the `lock` file is it a consequence or just a triviality

"Maybe if you include a reason will make it so easy to understand"